# Angle bisectors and circumscribed circle

Tags: circles

**AL and BM are bisectors in $\triangle ABC$. The second common point of the circles described (circumscribed) around $\triangle ACL$ and $\triangle BCM$ lies on the side AB. Find $\angle ACB$.**

I am not sure about the word "described" in the problem and if I am not right, I would be very grateful if you correct me.

Look at the drawing to understand what I have noticed. $$\alpha + \beta = 90^\circ - \frac{\gamma}{2} $$
$$ \angle AFB = 90^\circ + \frac{\gamma}{2}$$

I am not sure that these statements will help with the solution but I just want to show I have tried sth. 
[image]

Comment: This problem is screaming for an inversion with center at $C$.

Comment: @user647486, I am 8th grade, and I don't know what inversion is. Also, I am not sure what you advise me to do in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it also given that $M$ and $L$ are centers of the circles?

Comment: @Vasya, no it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin {cases}\angle AEC=\angle ALC=\pi-\alpha-\gamma\\
\angle BEC=\angle BMC=\pi-\beta-\gamma\\
\alpha+\beta=\pi/2-\gamma/2
\end {cases}\\
\implies
\pi=\angle AEC+\angle BEC=(\pi-\alpha-\gamma)+(\pi-\beta-\gamma)=\frac32 (\pi-\gamma).
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your response! But why we use $\pi$ here? Does it signify degrees?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova $\pi=180^\circ $. If you wish replace it everywhere.

Comment: As I see you used $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ for the full  angles, right? (not their halves as in my drawing)?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova I have used $\alpha$ and $\beta $ for the half-angles as in your drawing, and $\gamma $ for the full angle $C $ as in your question.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Because it is equal $\angle BMC $.

Comment: Okay, I got that but how to find $\angle ACB$ then? Sorry for the questions but I really want to understand it. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @NikolDimitrova What kind of problem do you have with solving the last equation?

Comment: I can solve it ($\gamma = 60^\circ$), but I don't know where does it come from...

Comment: @NikolDimitrova It comes from the solution of the equation. And you solved it correctly!

Comment: Nah, I don't understand how to write the equation after I had put the degrees on the drawing. [DRAWING](https://imgur.com/IO0b8RD)

Comment: $\frac {3}{2} (\pi - \gamma)$ ?

Comment: $(\pi-\alpha-\gamma)+(\pi-\beta-\gamma)$ !

Comment: I understand that this sum must be equal to $180^\circ$. But from where did you get $\frac {3}{2} (\pi - \gamma)$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova From the equation $\alpha+\beta=\pi/2-\gamma/2$ which was derived already in *your* question.